# Identifying distinct item in a C# list after spliting the value

Tags: c#, list, loops, optimization, .net-4.0

I am using C# (.NET 4.0). I have a

```
class Employee
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FilterType { get; set; }

    public Employee(string name, int id, string fType)
    {
        Location = name;
        ID = id;
        FilterType = fType;
    }
}


List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

Employee e = new Employee("[IND].[MH].&1", 1, "="); empList.Add(e);
e = new Employee("[SNG].[Tampines].&1", 7, "="); empList.Add(e);
e = new Employee("[IND].[MP].&2", 5, "="); empList.Add(e);
e = new Employee("[USA].[NYC].&2", 9, "="); empList.Add(e);
e = new Employee("[IND].[MH].&3", 3, "="); empList.Add(e);
e = new Employee("[IND].[MP].&1", 4, "="); empList.Add(e); 
e = new Employee("[SNG].[Bedok].&1", 6, "="); empList.Add(e);
e = new Employee("[USA].[NYC].&1", 8, "="); empList.Add(e);
e = new Employee("[IND].[MH].&2", 2, "="); empList.Add(e);
```

What I want to do :

1. Split the 'name' property in the empList by '.&'
2. This will return an array of 2 items. I will add array[0]into a dictionary.
3. This will create list of unique items (Lets call it unique list)
4. Then for every item in the unique list, I will loop over every item in empList and I will combine the name like this

if the item in unique list is '[USA].[NYC]', after looping over the empList, the output should be {[USA].[NYC].&1, [USA].[NYC].&2}. If the item in unique list is '[SNG].[Tampines]' the putput should be '{[SNG].[Tampines].&1}'

I can achieve this by doing something like this

Run a loop over empList - Split the name by '.&' and add the result in dictionary to ensure only unique items are added

Then run a loop over unique list - inside this loop run another loop on empList and check if the current item in empList contains item of uniqueList and do the string manipulation.

I wonder if there is a smarter way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: You are focusing *way* too much on mechanics. It would be far more fruitful to describe what you are trying to achieve, because whatever that is it definitely sounds this is not the way to do it. For starters, why is `Location` a dumb string?

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for the comment. The only reason I gave so much detail is because usually people ask, what have u tried? Why loaction is dumb string - This is the format in which data is stored cube (SSAS). I need to manipulate the keys to form query.

Comment: TL;DR: Describe your goal at a higher abstraction level. Kudos for the good intentions, but "mechanics" and "detail" are not the same thing. "I want to group widgets by owner and find the owner having the most" is detail. "I want to split on .& and transform [X].[Y] to {[X].[Y]&1....}" is mechanics. Actually it doesn't sound like you want to *split* per se. You want to do *something else* and you figured that splitting is the way to do it, but on that count you are probably wrong. See [what is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Jon: 'XY problem' makes sense. Message received :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier way. You can use the LINQ group by functionality:

```
    var grouped = from emp in empList
                  group emp by emp.Location.Split('&')[0] into g
                  select new {LocCode = g.Key, Emps = g};

    foreach (var group in grouped) {
        // group.LocCode contains, e.g., [USA].[NYC].,
        // group.Emps contains all employees at this location
    }
```